# Access iPad pictures from C#

Tags: c#, ipad, path

I can access pictures on my iPad via "Computer\Apple iPad\Internal Storage\DCIM\860OKMZO", but this is not a path that C# recognises if I'd want to start a FileSystemWatcher.

What would be the way to access these files? I presumed that if Explorer understands the path, so would C#.

Comment: The basic problem is that iPads/iPhones/cameras that appear as "Portable Devices" aren't mapped onto the file system with a drive letter. I'm doing some research on the subject right now and it appears that programmatically accessing a portable device is fairly tricky and not particularly well-documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues to overcome.

To access the device, you might need the name (a well known [NT Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#namespaces) device name).

On my computer, I can find my iPhone at \.\IPOD0\ for example.

However, the iPhone/Pad/Pod isn't using a standard file system when you browse it. It's using DCF (if you look at the "Internal Storage Properties" using Windows Explorer, you'll see that). That would be the [Design rule for Camera File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rule_for_Camera_File_system).

On Windows, as these devices are reporting as DCF file systems, you might investigate the WIA and an example (in C++) like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms629850%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Alas, that's not a FileSystemWatcher though. Unfortunately, the FileSystemWatcher (and other native Windows file operations) do not work with devices that respond as DCF file systems.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did some WIA stuff in the past, but that was ages ago; I forgot that this might be the way to go for aquiring the data. The main reason for looking into this, was that I used Photo Stream with a FileSystemWatcher, but Photo Stream stopped working :) I have it back working now, so there isn't a direct need to access the images directly anymore, but I might just do it for kicks. Thanks :)