# What protocol does the Windows explorer use for mobile devices?

Tags: windows, device, explorer

When connecting a mobile device like my navigation or my cell (non-apple) cell iPhone via USB to my Windows-PC, I get an almost explorer view of the device's file. "Almost" because it lacks a drive letter and the explorer features seem be limited, too. So it's not the normal file system.

What kind of protocol or API is this?

(I'm asking, because I'd like to enable my software to access this data, too.)

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465045/access-ipad-pictures-from-c-sharp

Comment: WAI or something similar, probably.

Comment: From your description, it appears to be a custom shell namespace extension. If you want to access the device directly, then you'll have to ask the people who wrote the extension how they did it. Or you can be like Explorer and let the shell extension do the work by navigating the shell namespace.